# Помогите пожалуйста решить

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

***Задача:***

> Есть два стакана. Каждый вмещает 150 миллилитров воды. В первом налито
>   `a` миллилитров жидкости, а во втором — `b` миллилитров жидкости.
>   Сколько надо долить жидкости в каждый из стаканов, чтобы суммарно в
>   них оказалось `c` (`a` + `b`)?
>
> Входные данные:
>   В единственной строке даны три целых числа `a`, `b`,
>   `c` (0 ≤ `a`, `b` ≤ 150; 1 ≤ `c` ≤ 300).
>
> Выходные данные:
>   Выведите два целых числа — объём воды, который
>   нужно долить в каждый из стаканов.

*Примеры:*

```py
140 10 170
10 10
```

```py
10 10 21
1 0
```

***Код:***

```py
a, b, c = [int(x)for x in input().split()]
r = a + b
v = c - r

if a > b:
    x = 150 - a
    y = c - (x + a) - b
    print(x, y)
if a < b:
    y = 150 - b
    x = c - a - (b + y)
    print(x, y)
if a == b:
    d = c - a - b
if a < 150:
    x=d
    y=0
else:
    y = d
    x = 0
    print(x, y)
```

*P. S.:* Только начала программировать, и лет еще не 12 даже, так что не судите строго.

Comment: Мария, расскажи что именно не получается. Потому что если мы тебе напишем решение целиком, то пользы от этого будет немного.

Comment: Если только начала программировать и лет еще даже не 12, то надо начать с чего-нибудь попроще, сообразно возможностям

Comment: Я все написала не понимаю как и что сравнивать

Comment: Тогда приведите пример кода и опишите, что не ясно

Comment: a, b, c=[int(x)for x in input().split()]
 
r=a+b
v=c-r
if a>b:
    x=150-a
    y=c-(x+a)-b
    print (x,y)
if a<b:
    y=150-b
    x=c-a-(b+y)
    print (x,y)
if a == b:    
    d=c-a-b
    if a<150:
        x=d
        y=0
    else:
        y=d
        x=0
    print(x,y)

Comment: @МарияЛоскутова Я добавил Ваш код в вопрос, но не уверен в правильности расстановки отступов. Проверьте его, пожалуйста, и, в случае неточности, измените, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Расскажу как я учил Python    Сразу полез в учебники по синтаксису языка . И потом библиотеки ,и т.д . Но очень важно понимать что нужна математика и логика . Я себя тренировал так : когда было очень скучно на листочке рисовал аглоритм , (если не понятно подходил к учителю спрашивал ) потом прилетал домой и писал код ( после домашки конечно ) .И вот так потихоньку пошло поехало . Но параллельно налегал на матиматику . Сейчас продолжаю учится и параллельно пишу на питоне . Вот как -то такой путь был у меня. И кстати удачи и никогда не сдавайся как тяжело не было бы .

Comment: И начни с баз языка . Например Хауди Хо Python за час !

Comment: Нет, пожалуйста, только не смотри Хауди

Comment: @whizz169 Чем Хауди то не нравится ?

Comment: Ах да можешь посмотреть лекции Тимофея Хирьянового ! Вот ссылок: [тут](https://m.youtube.com/user/tkhirianov/playlists)

Answer (score 1):

Вы немного перемудрили с решением))

В коде все шаги прокомментировал, если что не понятно - в комментариях отвечу.

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
neededa = c - (a + b)  # сначала дольем в стакан а столько, сколько сможем, не обращая внимания на его вместимость

# Дальше проверим стакан а на переполненность:
if a + neededa > 150:
    overlevel = (a + neededa) - 150  # "Отольем" воду из этого стакана, чтобы в нем осталось 150 мл
    neededa = 150 - a  # в стакан a нужно жидкости 150 - a
    neededb = overlevel  # Все остально выливаем в стакан b
else:
    a += neededa  # в стакане а стало на neededa больше жидкости
    neededb = c - (a + b)  # нужно дополнить стакан b, чтобы a + b было равно с
print(neededa, neededb)
```

Input: `10 10 21`, output: `1 0`

Input: `140 10 170`, output: `10 10`

Input: `150 0 245`, output: `0 95`